# NodeJS using node-static and restify together

Tags: javascript, node.js, restify, node-static

I'm creating a simple testing platform for an app and have the following code setup as my `server.js` file in the root of my app:

```
var restify = require('restify'),
    nstatic = require('node-static'),
    fs = require('fs'),
    data = __dirname + '/data.json',
    server = restify.createServer();


// Serve static files
var file = new nstatic.Server('');
server.get(/^\/.*/, function(req, res, next) {
    file.serve(req, res, next);
});


// Process GET
server.get('/api/:id', function(req, res) {
    // NEVER FIRES
});
```

It serves static files perfectly, however, when I try to make a call to the `/api` it just hangs and times out. Imagine I'm missing something stupid here, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You could check the header to see whats going on when you attempt to hit the api and/or put a breakpoint on your api method to see if it ever gets hit.

Comment: I `console.log`ed the `/api` get call and it just never reaches it. Beyond that it just times out.

Comment: Does nstatic `serve` use `next` when a file cannot be served? Otherwise you would have to move the second get before the first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may make yourself sure the api get call is caught by moving the second `get` before the first. The reason is your api calls routes are already matched by the first pattern.

Answer (score 3):

node-static is calling next with an error, which means it's never yielding to other handlers.

You can move your other handlers above node-static or ignore it's errors by intercepting it's callback.

I made a working version here: http://runnable.com/UWXHRONG7r1zAADe